# Original question, but the OP was looking for something else: how to deal?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31626/current-multiplier-divider/31667#comment60614_31667) is about current multiplier/divider ICs The OP asks if there are existing ICs that can be used to mirror a current with a fixed ratio, different than 1:1.

In the comments to Steven's answer, he's explained that he needs to measure a current, and the problem can be solved with a current sense amplifier. Though, there are other questions about that, while the original one is more (sorry for that) original.

Should we keep it and make the answers scoped? Or should we modify it to the real problem, making it a possible duplicate?

Comment: I think the question is interesting enough to keep it, even though he was actually looking for something else. OP should have been more clear about what problem he wants to solve so that answers could look at it both ways: the pros and cons of his proposed solution and why another solution would be better.

Comment: Note that the question *was* tagged `current-measurement`.

Comment: @stevenvh I should look at tags, from time to time :) buy yes, I think that we should answer the question directly, and also suggest the convenient way to measure the current, eventually pointing to other posts.

Comment: [OT] In italian, same like in Dutch  "eventualmente" seems to be a "false friend". It isn't translated as "eventually", that means "alla fine". I guess you mean "possibly". :-)

Comment: @stevenvh right! I thought it had a double use, but I always translate too literally :)

Comment: "eventualmente" doesn't sound like a Dutch word. I would have expected "eventualijk".

Comment: @ThePhoton - Yes, I know, I cut a corner in that line. `In Italian, same like the Dutch "eventueel", "eventualmente" seems to be a "false friend".` Better? :-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to answer an interesting question applicable to a public audience, not solve the original poster's problem. The new info would change the question entirely, so it should be asked separately. (If it's an exact duplicate, it shouldn't be asked at all -- a comment with a link will do.)

Comment: Uhm, that's pretty much the way I see it, also